# Can I use useRouter (from next/router) to initialize React state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

My initial state depends on pathname.
I receive pathname with hook useRouter.
Can I use received pathname to initialize state in useState?

```
const { pathname } = useRouter();
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(() => isMyPathname(pathname));
```

It works, but I didn't find such examples. So I'm not sure it's correct.
Piece of code:

```
    const { pathname } = useRouter();
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(() => isMyPathname(pathname));

    const onCLickHandler = () => {
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
      ...
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      if (isMyPathname(pathname)) {
        setIsOpen(false);
      } else ...

      prevPath.current = pathname;
    }, [pathname]);
```

Comment: It won't work when the path will change to the same component

Comment: If data can be determined from other variables you should not store it in the state

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I use it only to set initial state (for first render, I need state depends on path).

If path changes - I use useEffect with setIsOpen.

Comment: Still you should just use normal variable instead of state.

Comment: But then how to update state (isOpen) if use normal variable?

And I don't understand, why "If data can be determined from other variables you should not store it in the state". According to doc:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state

Comment: If path changes component will rerender anyway. You do not need state for that, i guess. You can simply define what your react component returns based on pathname

Comment: @TusharShahi I need value for state `isOpen` for first render. I use func to get it (because isOpen depends on path).
But then I need to update isOpen, when user click a button - I use onClickHandler where set `setIsOpen(true/false)`.